# How to set archive bit on a directory using os.stat?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am using a homebrew app called PyNX on my Nintendo Switch console, which is a custom Python 3.5 interpreter. I want to be able to run a script to set the archive bit on a directory with this program. I am very unfamiliar with the 'os' module's inner workings (I usually deal mostly with PyCrypto when using Python).

In the script, I want to first check if a directory's archive bit is set, and if it is, notify me, wait for input, then set the bit. If not, then do nothing and wait for input before exiting the script. I can fill in the path myself, so just use chkbasepath =  for the base path variable, and I'll replace '' with my desired path.

For relevancy to other users, it is preferred that the script be in a format that Python 3.5 for Windows could use as well, so it doesn't have to match the syntax of PyNX specifically. However, I would prefer a method that does not rely on the win32api or win32con modules, since those are not included with PyNX. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might get more useful responses asking around on forums for the community of people who run Python on their Switches. I don't know where those people hang out, though.

Comment: I can tell you that `os.stat` is not how you set the archive bit, though. `os.stat` might be useful for reading the archive bit, but not for writing it.

Comment: @user2357112 I already asked in the official Discord for it, and am still waiting on a response. What is a good method for writing the archive bit? I searched for SF_ARCHIVED on my entire Python35 directory, but no results seem relevant.

Comment: Can you find your local equivalent of changing any of the other `stat` bits? If you can and its implementation is transparent, maybe you can add it yourself.